# Concept: what is the use of glDrawBuffer and glDrawBuffers?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, framebuffer

I am reading the red book OpenGL programming guide when I come across these two methods, which strikes me as unnecessary since we already can specify which color buffer the output is going to go to with `layout (location = )` or `glBindFragDataLocation`. Am I misunderstanding anything here?

Comment: IIRC, unless you call glDrawBuffers, you can only render to the 0-th framebuffer attachement, regardless of `layout (location = ...)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not all color attachments which are attached to a framebuffer have to be rendered to by a shader program. [`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml) specifies a list of color buffers to be drawn into.

e.g. Lets assume you have a frambuffer with the 3 color attchments `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2`:

*Fragment shader*

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 out_color1;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 out_color2;
```

*drawbufferr specification:*

```
const GLenum buffers[]{ GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers( 2, buffers );
```

`out_color1` sends its data to the draw buffer at index 0 (because of the `location = 0` declaration). The call to `glDrawBuffers` above sets this buffer to be `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2`. Similarly, `out_color2` sends its data to index 1, which is set to be `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. Attachment 1 doesn't get data written to it.